# aria-expanded not allowed on input-element

Tags: wai-aria

I have the following HTML-Code:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="zip-city">Search for ZIP/City</label>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input aria-autocomplete="list" id="zip-city" type="text" name="zip_city"  aria-expanded="true" aria-owns="select-city-list">
        
        <ul id="select-city-list" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" class="city-selector" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">
            <li role="option" id="zip_112" data-uid="112" tabindex="-1">9999 myCity</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user types something into the input-field, I'm doing an ajax request and populate the `<ul id="select-city-list" […] >` with the results. Then I set the attribute `aria-expanded` on the input field to indicate that the connected list is expanded.
However, when I use the axe DevTools inspector, it tells me `ARIA attribute is not allowed: aria-expanded="true"`.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The inputfield is working as the trigger for the list, so I can't set this to another element.
I tried `aria-controls` instead of `aria-owns` to no avail.
Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a combobox if it has a dropdown list.  Adding `role="combobox"` to the <input> will eliminate the Axe warning.

The spec for [`aria-expanded`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-expanded) has a list of element types where the attribute is valid, under "Used in Roles". "Combobox" is one of them.  A default <input> element has a role of "textbox", which is **not** in the list of valid roles.

If you use `role="combobox"` then you should check out the other suggested attributes in the [combobox design pattern in the authoring practice guide (apg)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/).